# MySQL - datediff days (keep several decimal)

Tags: mysql, date, datediff

Please set the table below. When I use `datediff`(StartDate, SubmittedOn), I get only int type days, which is not accurate. So how to get the late one? Thank you.

```
StartDate        SubmittedOn        what I get using datediff   what I am tring to get
9/7/2016 13:12  9/1/2016 0:00        6                          6.550520833
9/1/2016 16:22  9/1/2016 0:00        0                          0.682048611
9/9/2016 13:30  9/1/2016 0:00        8                          8.562708333
9/9/2016 13:31  9/1/2016 0:00        8                          8.563472222
9/9/2016 16:08  9/1/2016 0:00        8                          8.672407407
9/2/2016 16:08  9/1/2016 0:00        1                          1.672685185
9/2/2016 16:01  9/1/2016 0:00        1                          1.667465278
```

Comment: You don't need to post another question, I've voted to re-open your previous one as it was incorrectly closed. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498310/mysql-date-difference-keep-two-decimal)

Comment: @Shaharyar     Since Gordon Linoff gave me the right solution at here. Just let the old questions close...Through that was closed incorrectly....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The previous question did seem to be incorrectly closed.

In any case, you want to take the difference in a smaller time unit and convert to days.  For instance:

```
select t.*,
       timestampdiff(second, startdate, submittedon) / (24 * 60 * 60) as days_with_fraction
from t;
```

Comment: Yes, that question was closed by misunderstanding.
You solve my issue now! good solution! I get the same results! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing TIMEDIFF instead of DATEDIFF.

[more here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)